# Issue with NSDictionary

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

I have a function to convert html symbol from strings and then insert them into NSDictionary. I guess its probably method or syntax error.

Function to convert html value:

```
  - (NSString *)convertMathSymbol:(NSString *)str{

         str = [str stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"&minus;" withString:@"− "];
         str = [str stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"&divide;" withString:@"÷ "];
         str = [str stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"&multiply;" withString:@"× "];

         return str;
    }
```

inserting into NSDictionary:

```
 NSString *tempAns1 = [[sample objectAtIndex:0]objectAtIndex:1];
 [answer setObject:[[self convertMathSymbol:tempAns1] forKey:@"1"]];
```

Error:

```
No visible @interface for 'NSString' declares the selector 'forKey:'
```

Appreciate any pointers... Thanx in advance...

Comment: check both tempAns1 and function returining string has value...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You *are* sending a message to an NSString*, let me show you how.

You have:

```
 [answer setObject:[[self convertMathSymbol:tempAns1] forKey:@"1"];
```

Strip away the answer dictionary receiver, and you get:

```
 [[self convertMathSymbol:tempAns1] forKey:@"1"];
```

See what I mean?

Try:

```
 [answer setObject:[self convertMathSymbol:tempAns1] forKey:@"1"];
```

Comment: In fact, this should give you some major warnings in itself, as the leading bracket is never closed.

Comment: I believe every other answer here deserves an upvote, wouldn't you say @TeamStar?

Answer (score 2):

Change this

```
[answer setObject:[[self convertMathSymbol:tempAns1] forKey:@"1"];
```

to this:

```
[answer setObject:[self convertMathSymbol:tempAns1] forKey:@"1"];
```

You've got an extra '[' before `[self convertMathSymbol:tempAns1'` which is confusing the compiler. The way you've written it, you're sending a message `forKey:` to the result of `[self convertMathSymbol:tempAns1]`. Pretty simple...

Answer (score 2):

Your brackets on the second line are not balanced. you have 3 ['s and 2 ]'s.